# Oracle : Who created a role?

Tags: oracle

I have a role in Oracle and I would like to know the user who created it.

```
select * from DBA_ROLES ;
select * from sys.user$ ;
```

The queries were not of much help for me.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Not possible unless you turned on auditing (before the roles were created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have auditing turned on then you should be able to see this information in `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL`:

```
SELECT
   username
  ,extended_timestamp
  ,owner
  ,obj_name
  ,action_name
FROM dba_audit_trail
WHERE action = 52 --CREATE ROLE
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Check the value of `audit_trail` to see if it is on:

```
SELECT value
FROM v$parameter
WHERE NAME = 'audit_trail'
;
```

This [article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2.php) explains auditing a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from below query.

```
SQL> SELECT rp.grantee, rp.granted_role, rp.admin_option
FROM dba_role_privs rp
JOIN dba_users u
  ON rp.grantee = u.username
WHERE admin_option = 'YES'
ORDER BY grantee, granted_role;  2    3    4    5    6

GRANTEE                        GRANTED_ROLE                             ADM
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- ---
ADMIN1                         DBA                                      YES
CTXSYS                         CTXAPP                                   YES
LBACSYS                        LBAC_DBA                                 YES
SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR          SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN                        YES
SYS                            ADM_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASK                YES
SYS                            APPLICATION_TRACE_VIEWER                 YES
SYS                            AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE                    YES
```